# One-page scroll script not working from another page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have created a one-page scroll, which works from home page.

**The problem: From the blog page, if I click 'contact' page, it should go to home page and scroll down to the contact section.**

At the moment I get the following error in console when I click contact from blog page.

```
script.js?ver=2017:24 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (script.js?ver=2017:24)
at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)
at HTMLAnchorElement.r.handle (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)
```

I realise the problem is with my script, particularly with this line: `scrollTop: jQuery(sectionID).offset().top` ?

I've put together the code from a tutorial video, so I am not exactly sure what is wrong. What is wrong in the code? Ideas? This is [The Site.](http://radian3.com/blog)

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    // add a click listener to each <a> tags
    setBindings();

    // burger nav
    jQuery(".burger-nav").on("click", function() {
        jQuery(".header-nav").toggleClass("open");  
    });

});

/* ONE PAGE NAVIGATION FUNCTION */
  function setBindings() {
    jQuery('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
  console.log('#someButton was clicked');

      // Get the href attribute, which includes '#' already
      var sectionID = jQuery(this).attr('href') + "-View";

      jQuery("html, body").animate({
        // Find target element
        scrollTop: jQuery(sectionID).offset().top
      }, 1000)
    });
  }
```

Comment: above this  **scrollTop: jQuery(sectionID).offset().top 
console (sectionID)** and check section id is defined or undefined

Comment: Id is coming out as defined i.e. #contact-View, the scroll works on home page - just not FROM blog. ideas?

Comment: You should be kidding me. You do not have those ID's in your page. Then how can it be scroll to that ID.?? IT works in the **home** page because you have that ID in Home page.

Comment: So there is no way to do the following: Go to home.php and scroll to the id? That is what I was trying to do

Comment: @Shaz, The Js code does not work like that. when you page loads a new page in your case  - "home.php". The `js` reloads the page and the event you executed will be not there. you have 2 options in my knowledge. 1, use **local storage** and 2 use a **plugin** for this situation.

Comment: Out of interest, is the animation important?  Essentially, you just want to load a new page and go to an anchor.  Why not just include the anchor in the url, and just load that url.  It will scroll automatically.
as @JithinRajPR pointed out, you can't carry state across the pages, except with things like cookies, localstorage, get parameters etc.

Comment: Well, even if I remove the animating scroll feature. the problem remains: from blog.php I cannot go the home.php -> #contact-View div ?